# Magmi is not changing attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I use Magmi Datapump to import my products. However, it seems Magmi does not update products properly. If I import the array below, current values of product with sku 90324/13 remain unchanged:

```
    Array
(
    [sku] => 90324/13
    [store] => admin,ledworld
    [status] => Enabled
    [bol_export] => 0
    [amazon_export] => 0
    [supplier_stock] => 0
    [supplier_expected_stock] => 18/07/2016
    [expected_delivery] => 19/07/2016
)
```

It doesn't matter if i reindex it, use update or create mode, no changes are made to the product, even though Magmi says the SKUS were imported succesfully.

Does someone have any ideas what i going on here?

EDIT: Even though the question is found to off topic I have some new info. It turned out it has something to do with the flat catalog for products, once the flat catalog is off, the field aren't updated. If the flat catalog is on, the field are updated. I hope this helps sombody.